# Write a faster coroutine in c without setjmp

Tags: c, coroutine

I'm writing a simple coroutine using `setjmp` and `longjmp` according to the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coroutine#Implementations_for_C).

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <setjmp.h>

jmp_buf orig;

void foo()
{
    printf("Hello from a coroutine!\n");
    longjmp(orig, 1);
}

int main()
{
    char *coroutine_stack = malloc(8192);
    coroutine_stack += 8192;    //move to the bottom of this allocated space, i.e., top of the coroutine's stack
    coroutine_stack -= 16;      //make it 16-byte aligned

    if(setjmp(orig) == 0)       //save the stack frame
    {
        asm(
            "movq %0, %%rsp "
            :
            : "rm" (coroutine_stack)
            :
        );                     //change the stack pointer to the already malloc'd region
        foo();
        //this should never be touched
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Return from a coroutine\n");
    return 0;
}
```

However, the wiki says there could be a faster solution if I don't use `setjmp` and `longjmp`:

> Minimalist implementations, which do not piggyback off the setjmp and longjmp functions, may achieve the same result via a small block of inline assembly which swaps merely the stack pointer and program counter, and clobbers all other registers. This can be significantly faster, as setjmp and longjmp must conservatively store all registers which may be in use according to the ABI, whereas the clobber method allows the compiler to store (by spilling to the stack) only what it knows is actually in use.

I'm a little confused about this because I already know that `setjmp` preserves callee-saved registers, but I don't know a way to instruct the compiler to preserve the registers that are *actually in use*.

Comment: I know there's a couple of C coroutine libraries floating around that you might take a look at to see what they do. And there's `setcontext()`/`getcontext()`/etc. in Unix land.

Comment: @Shawn, Thanks for your reply. The reason why I'm making my own wheel is out of curiosity, so I want to know if there is some compiler magic involved. And `setcontext`/`getcontext` seems deprecated with a little googling.

Comment: "//make it 16-byte aligned" That line of code does not align anything.

Comment: Why do you want it faster? How often does a longjmp happen? Note that the three requirements a) faster coroutine, b) C language and c) without setjmp are likely to be contradictory. Any asm() is certainly not C.

Comment: @Gerhardh, Thanks for pointing it out! The purpose of this line was to make `coroutine_stack` pointing to the very bottom of the malloc'd region, as well as keeping it aligned, as the stack grows from high address to low address. I think I should make sure that the malloc'd region is aligned first.

Comment: @Jens, I'm asking the question like this because the wiki says there could be a faster `minimalist implementation`, and I'm curious about how to turn that into code. `longjmp` is rarely called when used as exception handling, but I feel this is not true in coroutines. I'm sorry if the name of the question makes you think that only pure c is accepted. But coroutines require a seperate stack, which I think is beyond my knowledge in pure c );

Comment: Normally, `malloc` returns an area of memory that is aligned to maximum alignment needs. The alignment of th buffer itself is not a problem. As long as your offset is also aligned, there should also not be a problem.